# Arabic/English text being shuffled

Tags: asp.net, textbox, arabic

I have been stocked in a strange problem
I have a text box and i am trying to read the text. But when the text box contains both arabic and english text it seems that the text is shuffled . This is how i read my text from text box:

```
string temp = input.Text;
```

This is text that i am inserting in text box:

> باهم and englishمتن فارسی

And this is the text that i get from textbox:

> متن فارسی and english باهم

Comment: Where are you seeing the shuffled text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add RLE char at the beginning of the text.

```
const char RightToLeftEmbedding = (char)0x202B;
```

Answer (score 0):

Arabic is a right to left language.  English is left to right.  So that actually is correct-  the arabic on screen will be in opposite order (string position 0 will be on the far right).

Comment: It depends on the embedded bidi controls characters.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a problem with ASP.NET, but with the HTML that it outputs.

Inspect the HTML elements in the browser and check the "direction" property in the computed style. If the main language of your input box is Arabic or Persian, it should be "rtl", and if it's English, then it should be "ltr". If it's the other way, you need to adjust it by using the appropriate dir attribute on the HTML elements.

This only adjusts it for the user interface. The text is probably saved into your database not with the correct direction, but that may be fine, because the database is internal and usually not seen by users.